# Karate: Assign specific value to a variable from a response

Tags: karate

I have a scenario where I have to get the value from a hyperlink in the response and assign it to a variable, which I can pass this variable into the url. Here is the json response

```
{
  "activationDate": "2019-08-20T14:39:07.953",
  "expirationDate": "2023-01-30T14:39:07.953",
  "timestamp": "637078348862871855",
  "links": [
    {


    "href": "https://someurl/api/data/c27f3dc3-dcf6-4958-a559-6bf222d880ce",
      "rel": "self"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://someurl/api/data/users/c27f3dc3-dcf6-4958-a559-6bf222d880ce",
      "rel": "credentials"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://someurl/api/access/data/c27f3dc3-dcf6-4958-a559-6bf222d880ce",
      "rel": "access"
    }
  ],
  "firstName": "APITest",
  "lastName": "User",
  "emailAddress": "apiuser@gmail.com",
  "ada": true,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "alerts": [
  ]
}
```

I need only this value "c27f3dc3-dcf6-4958-a559-6bf222d880ce" from the response which I can pass in the url in another scenario.

Not sure how can I get that value using get keyword in karate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in 2 steps:

```
* def temp = response.links[0].href
* def id = temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you Peter. This worked.
Really liking this tool for my API testing. Big shoutout to you.